# SQL AFTER Insert Trigger for Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to update the `lunTot` column after `lunOut` column value is inserted by using a trigger, but somehow it's not updating. If I use `Update` statement query it's working well.

After insert trigger (not working):

```
create trigger trg_AfterInsertLunTot
on lunTime
after insert
as
begin
    update lunTime
    set lunTot = DATEDIFF(minute, lunIn, lunOut) 
    from lunTime
end
go
```

With `Update` query (working)

```
update lunTime
set lunTot = DATEDIFF(minute, lunIn, lunOut) 
from lunTime
```

Comment: What is server are you using?  Make a `before` trigger, set the :new.lunTot variable, depending on your flavour of sql.

Comment: Not familiar enough with SQL Server.  Looks like you'll want an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just make `lunTot` a **computed** column? No need to use a trigger for this....

Just drop your existing `lunTot` column you have now

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.lunTime
DROP COLUMN lunTot
```

and then define it again as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE lunTime 
ADD lunTot = DATEDIFF(minute, lunIn, lunOut)
```

Now your column `lunTot` will *always* reflect the difference between `lunIn` and `lunOut` - for all existing row, and automagically after you insert new rows as well.